# Wrong source map for concatenated .js file in grunt-contrib-concat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, source-maps, grunt-contrib-concat

Recently I faced a very nasty problem with source mapping using grunt-contrib-concat. Grunt-contrib-concat concatenates several .js files into one and uses source-map module for source mapping. 
So breakpoints in my code paused incorrectly both in Chrome and in VS Code. (You know what is it, if you faced the same problem).
My environment: Windows 10, VS Code with Debugger for Chrome extension, Chrome browser, Node.js project with grunt-contrib-concat dependency.
It is very unefficient to debug your client-side code without correct breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent several hours to clear the problem, and finally I have found the solution. Problem was in concatenate minified .js files. After these minified files line numbers in source map become wrong.
So the solution is to exclude minified files and use normal instead.